# loop prints a error message multiple times

Tags: python, bioinformatics

edited for clarity.  When a loop prints an error message multiple times, it is usually caused by poor control flow. In this case, adding a `Break`after print solved the problem.

Following a simple loop structure with some control flow, is generally a good starting point.

```py
for ...:
    if ...:
        print ...
        break
```

```py
input_seq = "";

#raw_input() reads every input as a string
input_seq = raw_input("\nPlease input the last 12 nucleotide of the target sequence 
before the PAM site.\n\(The PAM site is by default \"NGG\"\):\n12 nt = ")

#print "raw_input =", input_seq
for bases in input_seq:
   if not (bases in "ACTGactg"):
       print "\nYour input is wrong.  Only A.T.C.G.a.t.c.g are allowed for 
       the input!\n\n";
       break
```

Comment: You could add a break statement right after the print (inside the if).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break`. I am using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to avoid using a `for` loop.

```
input_seq = ""
import re

while True:

  #raw_input() reads every input as a string
  input_seq = raw_input("\nPlease input the last 12 nucleotide of the target sequence 
   before the PAM site.\n\(The PAM site is by default \"NGG\"\):\n12 nt = ")

  #print "raw_input =", input_seq
  if len(input_seq)==12:
    match=re.match(r'[ATCGatcg]{12}',input_seq)
    if match:
      break
    else:
      print "\nYour input is wrong.  Only A.T.C.G.a.t.c.g are allowed for the input!\n\n"
      continue
  else:
    print "\nYour input should be of 12 character"
```

Comment: Thanks could you give a suggestion to a solution for my second question ?

Answer (score 0):

Place a `break` after the print:

```python
for ...:
    if ...:
        print ...
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `break` after your print statement. That will terminate your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using a flag to check if there were atleast one wrong input is one way to do it. Like this:

```
invalid = False
for bases in input_seq:
    if not (bases in "ACTGactg"):
        invalid = True

if invalid:
    print "\nYour input is wrong.  Only A.T.C.G.a.t.c.g are allowed for the input!\n\n";
```

You could alternately use a `break` statement as soon as you find the first wrong input.